# Prove that if $u\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ (Euclidean domain) is unit, then $v(u)=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, euclidean-domain

> Prove that if $u\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ (Euclidean domain) is unit, then $v(u)=1$.

Can someone let me know if this proof is okay?

Let $\alpha$ be unit. Then there exists an element $\beta  \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ such that $\alpha \beta = 1$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is Euclidean, then $1=v(\alpha \beta)\geq v(\alpha)$. Since $\alpha$ is non-zero, it must be that $v(\alpha)=1$.

Comment: What is $v$? ${}$

Comment: I think you need to justify that inequality. Why is it true? Note that the norm is actually multiplicative.

Comment: Presumably, $\nu$ is the Euclidean function that makes this ring a Euclidean domain; but, numer, this information should be given explicitly in the body of your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry about that, you're exactly right about what $v$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $u =a+b\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ then the norm of $u$ is defined as $$v(u)=\vert \vert u \vert \vert=\vert a^2-2b^2 \vert$$

The half of the battle is already done by you. For the other part, note that $1=v(1)$ is always the minimum ,since $$v(1) \leq v(1 \cdot u) =v(u)$$

Comment: Nowhere was it stated that $\nu(a+b\sqrt2)=|a^2-2b^2|$. There can be other Euclidean functions on a Euclidean domain.